# ionic 4 - setting page variable not working in iOS and Android, but browser OK in browser

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I'm using google maps and trying to show a div when the user clicks a pin.

```
<div *ngIf="this.viewing_place">
  {{ this.viewing_place?.title || 'NO_PLACE' }}
</div>

function redrawMap(){
  let self = this;
  this.places.forEach(function(place){
    let marker = self.map.addMarkerSync({ position :new LatLng(place.pin_lat, place.pin_long) });
    marker.on(GoogleMapsEvent.MARKER_CLICK).subscribe(() => {
      self.openPlaceInfo(place);
    });
  });
}
```

The click event is working good and the place object is being passed ok.

```
openPlaceInfo(place){
  console.log(place); //===========> shows correct object
  this.viewing_place = place; //======> set the page variable
}
```

The problem is that the **div is not being displayed**, like the variable `this.viewing_place` is not set.

So I created a manual method just for testing, and when I use this function, it works correctly.

```
manuallyTest(){
  this.viewing_place = {title:'test place'};
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? This happens only in iOS an Android.. It works perfectly in browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In mobile devices, angular has limitation calling change detection cycle when a variable updates from observable. I experienced this when I worked with Ionic. Try running you function inside `NgZone` to force the change detection cycle to re-render the UI.

```
constructor() {
  ...
  private zone: NgZone
}


marker.on(GoogleMapsEvent.MARKER_CLICK).subscribe(() => {
  this.zone.run(() => {
   self.openPlaceInfo(place);
  });
});

OR

openPlaceInfo(place){
  console.log(place); //===========> shows correct object
  this.zone.run(() => {
    this.viewing_place = place; //======> set the page variable
  });
}
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: it worked, you made my day! thank you! never had this kind of problem before!

Comment: Great! Keep this trick in the pocket, you will probably see this issue occurring in many places :)