# Ionic / Angular show latest added item on top (.reverse() not doing the job)

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am using Ionic / Angular in a project.

I have a variable where items are added at runtime by the user.

In my `.ts` file I have:

```
list: any[] = [];
```

then here is the html:

```
<ion-list *ngFor="let data of list; let i = index" id="{{i}}">
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>{{ data.name }}</ion-label>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

My issue is that I need to force it to display the latest added on top.

I've tried adding `.reverse()` like this:

```
<ion-list *ngFor="let data of list.reverse(); let i = index" id="{{i}}">
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>{{ data.name }}</ion-label>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

...but nothing changed.

How can I do this?

Comment: ionic has a fuss with angular's change detection cycle. You will need to do the reverse in the component.ts within ngZone for angular to run change detection, after the array has been modified. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72753427/5556177)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use .unshift() method to add item on top instead of reversing the List.

Comment: Add stops working when I try .unshift()

Comment: @zaknio55 make sure the list is in fact initialized (`list = []`) or already has elements before adding a new one. The `Array.prototype.unshift()` should work fine in this case.